# How to create a command for a Laravel 4 package?

Tags: php, laravel-4

The docs [says](http://laravel.com/docs/commands#building-a-command) that we can create a command for a package in Laravel 4.1 typing:

```
php artisan command:make AssignUsers --bench="vendor/package"
```

But it seems to not be working, I got the following error message:

> [RuntimeException]
>     The "--bench" option does not exist.

Is there a way to create a command for a Laravel 4 package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the standard artisan command to create a command into my package:

```
php artisan command:make CreateUsers \
    --path="workbench/vendor/package/src/vendor/package"
```

After that, to make it *available* in the consumer application I had to add the following into my package's ServiceProvider (in the boot method):

```
$this->app->bind('vendor::command.user.create', function($app) {
    return new UserCreateCommand();
});
$this->commands(array(
    'vendor::command.user.create'
));
```

After that, everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, Rubens.  Really helped me out.  Would you perhaps be able to let me know where you found this binding syntax for commands?  I can't find it in the documentation anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

when you run you will sse the list of arguments for make

> php artisan command:make --help

you should see something like

```
Usage:
 command:make [--command[="..."]] [--path[="..."]] [--namespace[="..."]] name

Arguments:
 name                  The name of the command.

Options:
 --command             The terminal command that should be assigned.
 --path                The path where the command should be stored.
 --namespace           The command namespace.
 --help (-h)           Display this help message.
 --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message.
 --verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
 --version (-V)        Display this application version.
 --ansi                Force ANSI output.
 --no-ansi             Disable ANSI output.
 --no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question.
 --env                 The environment the command should run under.
```

as you can see from that output there is no argument bench

the proper way to do it is

```
php artisan command:make AssignUsers
```

then go to /app/start/artisan.php  and add the following line

```
Artisan::add(new AssignUsers);
```

then edit the generated file in /app/commands/AssignUsers.php
change the value of  $name to  AssignUsers
and you are done.